# Error while running ORB_SLAM as a ROS node

Tags: ros, slam-algorithm

Following the tutorial provided in this [link](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2), I am trying to run ORB_SLAM as a ROS node in ROS Indigo. After executing the line /.build_ros.sh, I am facing a list of errors,

```
Building ROS nodes
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘build’: File exists
[rosbuild] Building package ORB_SLAM2
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/indigo/bin/rospack deps-manifests ORB_SLAM2
[rospack] Error: package 'ORB_SLAM2' depends on non-existent package 'image_transport' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'


CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):


  Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'ORB_SLAM2'.
  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
  broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:207 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ros/ORB_SLAM2-master/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ros/ORB_SLAM2-master/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
[rosbuild] Building package ORB_SLAM2
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/indigo/bin/rospack deps-manifests ORB_SLAM2
[rospack] Error: package 'ORB_SLAM2' depends on non-existent package 'image_transport' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'


CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):


  Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'ORB_SLAM2'.
  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
  broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:207 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ros/ORB_SLAM2-master/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ros/ORB_SLAM2-master/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

I am not able to resolve these errors, plese help in debugging this, if someone has faced the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the image_transport, try:

`rosdep update
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-image-transport`